# Nested LinearLayout not working in scrollview

Tags: android

I am facing a problem that in my `Compose.xml` there is nested `LinearLayout` in scroll but when I run the application scroll is not working:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

Comment: Are you sure the ScrollView's contents are tall enough to be able to scroll? That is, are you sure that some of your Buttons are actually off-screen on the bottom when it starts?

Comment: If i extend the  activity it wil run prefectly but if i exdend fragment it will not work.

Comment: You'd need to provide more details about your setup for us to be able to help. What container is your Fragment loaded into? Is it inside another View that  scrolls?

Comment: post your complete codes from where u are calling your fragment class.

Comment: @SiddharthKhetan check my answer its working

Comment: @siddharth your code also working in fragment, I had checked it. There are any other issue

Answer (score 3):

Its already scrolling in My device Moto X2
Your code hase no error, but it takes too much time to load.You can see scrollbar at right side in screenshot below.

[image: You can see scrollbar at right side in screenshot]

So don't use too much layout without need. More layouts will take more time to load data, You can also use Single Linear layout and put all buttons into that layout

**You can write your code like this :**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="erfer" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Dude thanks for taking interest but i thing u call this layout in activity neither in fragment ..In Activity it will work but in Fragment it will not work

Comment: I tested your and my code on activity and fragment both.
Both code is working well.

Comment: I am using android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why do you need that much linearLayouts there?
Try use one nested LinearLayout and put all the Buttons in it, one after another. Here's pseudocode.

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<Button/>
<Button/>
...
<Button/>
</LinearLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

Also, if it won't help, try to remove this

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` can have only one child. You can put these layout into one linear layout then your scroll view will work.

For more detail read [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: You can put these layout into one linear layout then your scroll view work file

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="erfer" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```